# How to get an index of list?

Tags: python

```
>>> ohlc = [(735981.0, 74.25, 77.25, 73.75, 75.75), 
            (735982.0, 76.5, 77.0, 75.0, 75.25),
            (735983.0, 75.75, 75.75, 74.25, 75.0),
            (735984.0, 75.0, 76.25, 74.5, 75.5)]
>>> print (ohlc.index("735982.0"))
>>> ValueError: '735982.0' is not in list
```

From code I want to get index result = 1 but i cant do this.

Thank you.

Comment: `"735982.0" != (735982.0, 76.5, 77.0, 75.0, 75.25)`

Comment: @Biffen Thank you for advise me now i understand why i get an error. but i still don't know the way to get the return of 1

Comment: `ohlc` contains 5-tuples of floats.  `"735982.0"` isn't a tuple, or even a number --- it's a string.  You'd have to convert the string to a float (using the built-in `float`), and then compare it to the first element of each tuple.  You might also have to do a fuzzy comparison of the floats ("is almost-equal to" instead of "is equal to"), depending on where they came from, since a tiny rounding error can make two floats unequal.

Comment: Now that I think of it... Why are you storing that data in a list of tuples anyway?  Wouldn't it be better as a dictionary keyed by the first float?  (Or is that first float not guaranteed to be unique?)  You could use a [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if the order of tuples in the list is important to you.

Comment: New in Python 3.5:  the [`math.isclose`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) function, for comparing floating-point numbers.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase The Op signed up to SO 3 days ago. Judging from the question, he is probably a beginner.  I would say, it may not be a good idea to suggest `collections.OrderedDict` in this post. Maybe, the best approach at this stage is just solving the problem he posted. BTW: if you're the one who down-voted all the answers (I am not saying you are) maybe it will be helpful to explain why. Again, I am not suggesting you're the down-voter, but I just thought I ask.

Comment: @JoeR:  Yes, I wandered off-topic a bit (hence the comments instead of an answer).  I thought this might be a case where the choice of data structure was making the problem harder to use than it had to be, and didn't look at the user's reputation.  (I didn't downvote anything either, for that matter --- I've been backporting `isclose` to my older Python and grumbling about complex numbers.)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like

```
[idx for idx,o in enumerate(ohlc) if o[0]==735982.0][0]

> 1
```

P.S. Make sure you add a try/catch in case the element does not exist in the list

Comment: Someone really likes to down-vote in this thread. Seems like almost every answer is down-voted.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ohlc` list is a list of tuple. So you have to give tuple to find the index value like this.

```
In [1]: ohlc = [(735981.0, 74.25, 77.25, 73.75, 75.75), 
   .....:             (735982.0, 76.5, 77.0, 75.0, 75.25),
   .....:             (735983.0, 75.75, 75.75, 74.25, 75.0),
   .....:             (735984.0, 75.0, 76.25, 74.5, 75.5)]
In [2]: ohlc.index((735982.0, 76.5, 77.0, 75.0, 75.25))
Out[1]: 1
```

Index is the position of a element in list. You can find the element using index also. Like `ohlc[1]`. It return the corresponding element.

If you want to find the index value with the `735982.0` float value you can implement like this.

```
In [3]: [i[0] for i in ohlc].index(735982.0)
Out[2]: 1
```

But always better to use `enumerate` to find the index value.

```
In [4]: for index,value in enumerate(ohlc):
   .....:     print index,"...",value
   .....:     
0 ... (735981.0, 74.25, 77.25, 73.75, 75.75)
1 ... (735982.0, 76.5, 77.0, 75.0, 75.25)
2 ... (735983.0, 75.75, 75.75, 74.25, 75.0)
3 ... (735984.0, 75.0, 76.25, 74.5, 75.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

`ohlc` is a list of tuples so,

You may do something like this to match only the first element of the tuples:

```
ohlc = [(735981.0, 74.25, 77.25, 73.75, 75.75),(735982.0, 76.5, 77.0, 75.0, 75.25),(735983.0, 75.75, 75.75, 74.25, 75.0),(735984.0, 75.0, 76.25, 74.5, 75.5)]
a=[ohlc.index(item) for item in ohlc if item[0] == 735981]
print(a)
```

**To search in all:**

```
ohlc = [(735981.0, 74.25, 77.25, 73.75, 75.75),(735982.0, 76.5, 77.0, 75.0, 75.25),(735983.0, 75.75, 75.75, 74.25, 75.0),(735984.0, 75.0, 76.25, 74.5, 75.5)]
num=75.0 #whichever number
```

***With list comprehension:***

```
a=[ohlc.index(item) for item in ohlc if num in item]
print(a)
```

***Without list comprehension:***

```
for item in ohlc:
   if num in item:
       print(ohlc.index(item))
```

Output:

```
0
2
```